# Как выполнить JS-функцию только один раз при скролле

Tags: jquery, javascript

Задача: доскроллил посетитель до определенного места на странице — выполнилась функция (вызов только один раз, ибо выполнение долгое и ресурсоемкое).
Как это сделать с jquery?
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    show_graphics();
}); — будет выполнять функицю «каждый скролл»

в самой функции проверяем позицию скролла, сравниваем с позицией элемента, если первое больше второго — выполняем функцию.
Но как выполнить ее ЛИШЬ ЕДИНОЖДЫ?

Comment: вы хотите запустить событие только если позиция скролла стала n ? Это невозможно. Если проверка действительно очень тяжелая, сделайте её асинхронной через srtTimeout, но скорее всего вам хватит просто оптимизировать эту проверку. в общем делайте пример и тогда вам можно будет что-то посоветовать.

Comment: и вот ещё: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @Елена Левина, one и unbind(после первого срабатывания) на скролл абсолютно бессмысленны, я думаю ТС хочет того что я написал а не перехватить единственное событие scroll.

Comment: one — да, точно.

Но вызов функции и unbind можно же делать по условию, проверяя scrollTop.

Answer (score 1):

можно в самой функции удалить обработчик на событие: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1):

Перепробовал ваши варианты, немножко поплевался и пришел к своему - простому, как валенок, но безотказно работающему способу. 
(ЗЫ. Сравнивал "*если скролл больше, чем начало секции #skills*").
1. Вне функции скролла добавил к элементу, который сработает один раз класс animate.
2. Внутри функции скролла поставил действие именно на этот элемент с классом animate.
Когда функция выполнится - удаляю класс animate. Всё, сработало один раз и больше не парит, все довольны :)

```
$('.skill_item div').addClass('animate');
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= $('#skills').offset().top ) {

        $('.skill_item div.animate').each(function(){
            // что-то делаем и...
            $(this).removeClass('animate');
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто, надо дать название данной привязке и анбидить её посде выполнения:

```
$(window).bind('scroll.once', function(){ 
   show_graphics(); 
});
function show_graphics() {
   //run code
   $(window).unbind('scroll.once')
};
```